# How did root of the equation $x= \sqrt{(2-x)(3-x)} + \sqrt{(3-x)(5-x)} + \sqrt{(2-x)(5-x)}$ vanish while solving?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

The original question was to solve for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ in:
$$x= \sqrt{(2-x)(3-x)} + \sqrt{(3-x)(5-x)} + \sqrt{(2-x)(5-x)}$$
My Solution:

By domain requirements: $x \in (-\infty,2) \cup (5,\infty) $.
\begin{align}
x &= \sqrt{(2-x)(3-x)} + \sqrt{(3-x)(5-x)} + \sqrt{(2-x)(5-x)} \\
\Rightarrow (x - \sqrt{(2-x)(3-x)})^2 &= (\sqrt{(3-x)(5-x)} + \sqrt{(2-x)(5-x)})^2 \\
\Rightarrow 2x^2 - 5x + 6 - 2x\sqrt{(2-x)(3-x)} &= 2x^2 - 15x + 25 + 2(5-x)\sqrt{(2-x)(3-x)} \\
\Rightarrow x - 1.9 &= \sqrt{(3-x)(2-x)} \\
\Rightarrow x \geq 1.9 &\hspace{0.5 cm}\&\hspace{0.5 cm}  (x - 1.9)^2 = (3-x)(2-x) \\
\Rightarrow x = \frac{239}{120}
\end{align}
**Question:** If I check for the answers of the original equation in WOLFRAM, I get two possible answers: $x = \frac{239}{120} $ and $x = \frac{1}{2}(5 + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{8 + 3\sqrt{5}})$. My question is where (and **why**) in my solution did the second root vanish? I have only used squaring and simplification, and as far as I know squaring only creates an additional root, it does not destroy a root.

Link to Wolfram's solution: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D+%5Csqrt%7B(2-x)(3-x)%7D+%2B+%5Csqrt%7B(3-x)(5-x)%7D+%2B+%5Csqrt%7B(2-x)(5-x)%7D

Comment: I got the same solution as you,$x=239/120$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error occurs at the step where you removed the factor $(5-x)$.

It should be $|5-x|$, which leads to two cases.

If $x \le 5$, then $(5-x)$ is correct.

If $x > 5$, the correct factor is $(x-5)$.

Comment: So basically $\sqrt{(2-x)(3-x)(5-x)^2} = (5-x) \sqrt{(2-x)(3-x)}$ if $x < 5$ and equals $(x-5) \sqrt{(x-2)(x-3)}$ if $x > 5$.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: So in general the law violated was: $(\sqrt{x})^2 = x$ iff $x \geq 0$. Thank you.

Comment: Not quite. Correct is this: For $x\in \mathbb{R}$, the law is: If $x\ge 0$, then $\sqrt{x^2}=x$. If $x < 0$, then $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$. In either case, we have $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.